# Script - Check CPU load (Python)

Tags: python

I've written for practicing purposes the following python script which checks the cpu load in case the processor reaches the 50% of the total usage.

```
import subprocess
import os

process1 = os.popen('cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -c processor')
cmdread1 = process1.read()
process1.close()
num_of_procs = int(cmdread1)/2
print num_of_procs    # returns 1

process = os.popen('cat /proc/loadavg | awk \'{print $1}\'')
cmdread = process.read()
process.close()
cpu_usage = cmdread
print cpu_usage   # returns 0.15 or 0.xx (there is no load at the moment)
if cpu_usage>num_of_procs: # check if 0.15 is greater than 1 
   print "load!"
else:
   print "no load"
```

The script always returns "load" which is false.
Moreover , I've check the boolean operations between a float and an integer and i see not something weird.
Do you have any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why you should use Python 3, where this programming error would have been visible easily.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you forgot to cast cpu_usage.
In the example below all required variables have been cast into float

```
import subprocess
import os

process1 = os.popen('cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -c processor')
cmdread1 = process1.read()
process1.close()
num_of_procs = float(cmdread1)/2.0
print (num_of_procs)    # returns 1

process = os.popen('cat /proc/loadavg | awk \'{print $1}\'')
cmdread = process.read()
process.close()
cpu_usage = float(cmdread)
print (cpu_usage)   # returns 0.15 or 0.xx (there is no load at the moment)
if cpu_usage>num_of_procs: # check if 0.15 is greater than 1 
   print ("load!")
else:
   print ("no load")
```

Comment: You are right ,it worked.thanks a lot Srgrn and guys from Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

cpu_usage is a string and num_of_procs is an Int.

So when you do:

```
if cpu_usage>num_of_procs:
```

it always returns false

Answer (score 0):

`cpu_usage` is a string, and `num_of_procs` an integer.

In Python 2, comparisons between strings and integers return an undefined value, cpython seems to always return True in your case.

You should cast `cpu_usage` to a number, like this:

```
cpu_usage = float(cmdread)
```

To avoid this class of errors, you can also use Python 3, where comparing types with no meaningful ordering between them raises an error:

```
>>> '0.001' < 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```